# Is Go compiler smart enough to pick up microoptimization?

Tags: go

I am curious whether it makes sense to use microoptimizations like

- `a / 2` versus `a >> 1` when a is an integer
- `a * 2` vs `a << 1`
- `a % 2` vs `a & 1`
- and some others like these

I know that any decent C compiler is good enough handle this. Also please do not write about premature optimization, because these techniques are so obvious, that it is not even optimization and more like a matter of preferences how to write code.

**P.S.** I tried to do benchmarks and the difference in timing is not statistically significant. I do not know how to check go's bytecode so thank you for pointing it.

Comment: Obvious to you, but maybe not the next guy working on your code :) Isn't it possible to check the Go byte code to see if there's any optimization done by the compiler?

Comment: To know for sure what is happening you'd need to look at the compiler output, perhaps with `go build -gcflags="-S"`.

Comment: Have you tried any benchmarks? These sorts of optimizations have been standard in compilers for at least two decades. Write code that makes sense and let the compiler optimize. If you have a situation where the compiler can't deal, write a comment in the form of an apology as to why you're writing such odd code.

Comment: E.g. you could examine the `go build -gcflags="-S"` output from something simple like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/KxkhL6hYzM). It would appear as if `a*2` is identical but the others are ever so slightly different (although I think equally as fast).

Comment: And it appears as if those differences go away if the type is `uint` vs `int`, likely due to algorithmic vs logical shift.

Comment: `because these techniques are so obvious, that it is not even optimization and more like a matter of preferences how to write code.` If these techniques are so obvious, why did you have to do side-by-side comparisons in your question? hint hint

Comment: @CoryDanielson I did it to explain what kind of microoptimization I am talking about. How would you expect me to write the question without mentioning them?

Comment: I'm pointing out the fact that this premature optimization is not as obvious as you're implying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76690/discussion-between-salvador-dali-and-cory-danielson).

Comment: I really don't care too. The overwhelming sentiment among the comments seems to disagree with your opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer, yes, the compiler optimises those.
But it does so slightly differently for `int` vs `uint` (and presumably any signed vs unsigned integer types such as `byte`).

In both cases multiplication and division instructions are avoided but it's only a single instruction for unsigned integers (and a small number of instructions for signed integers).
That's because your pairs of statments are only exactly equivalent for unsigned integers and not for signed integers.

**Longer answer:**

Taking a simple program like:

```
package main

func main() {}

func div2(a int) {
        b := a / 2
        c := a >> 1
        _, _ = b, c
}

func mul2(a int) {
        b := a * 2
        c := a << 1
        _, _ = b, c
}

func mod2(a int) {
        b := a % 2
        c := a & 1
        _, _ = b, c
}
```

and running `go build -gcflags="-S"` will give you assembly output such as:

```
"".mod2 t=1 size=32 value=0 args=0x8 locals=0x0
        0x0000 00000 (…/opt.go:17)       TEXT    "".mod2+0(SB),4,$0-8
        …
        0x0000 00000 (…/opt.go:17)       MOVQ    "".a+8(FP),BX
        …
        0x0005 00005 (…/opt.go:18)       MOVQ    BX,AX
        0x0008 00008 (…/opt.go:18)       SARQ    $63,AX
        0x000c 00012 (…/opt.go:18)       MOVQ    BX,DX
        0x000f 00015 (…/opt.go:18)       SUBQ    AX,DX
        0x0012 00018 (…/opt.go:18)       ANDQ    $1,DX
        0x0016 00022 (…/opt.go:18)       ADDQ    AX,DX
        0x0019 00025 (…/opt.go:19)       ANDQ    $1,BX
        0x001d 00029 (…/opt.go:21)       RET     ,
```

Here `BX` is the argument and `DX` and `BX` appear to be the two results
(`BX` being reused as one of the results).
Here they are slightly different, but only by a few instructions
(look at the source line numbers shown)
and without any division or multiplication instructions
(so basically just as fast).
The difference is due to algorithmic vs logical shifts and how Go does mod for negative values.

You can confirm this by changing `int` to `uint` in the program and then the output contains things like:

```
        0x0008 00008 (…/opt.go:18)       ANDQ    $1,CX
        0x000c 00012 (…/opt.go:19)       ANDQ    $1,BX
```

i.e. the exact same instruction.
This is true for each of the examples you gave.

Comment: It's important to note here that the compiler correctly identifies cases where the optimization can be made, such as on unsigned ints, and avoids those where it cannot be done, such as signed ints where potentially shifting the sign bit would be completely wrong.

Comment: Actually, it's more than "an instruction or two", but it doesn't have `DIVQ`, `MULQ`, or `IMULQ` that you see with "normal" math operations and as tadman rightly points out, they do need to be longer to be fully correct for signed integers.